# Getting meta in editor plugin, and event triggering issue

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, post-meta, rest-api, block-editor

I have a Custom Post Type defined with `custom-fields` support. I then registered a meta field.

**The first issue** is that `select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles` always returns `undefined` *on first call* (before being updated by `dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost`). Also, when I save the Custom post Type the value isn't modified in the database.

**The other issue is**, when check any of the checkboxes, on first click, `isChecked()` is properly called, on next clicks it doesn't happen, but `updateMeta()` is triggered. If I fold/unfold the control or uncheck a checkbox, all the checkboxes do get updated by calling `isChecked()`:

[image: animation example of second issue]

Here is my code:

```php
class Metaboxes extends Base {

    /**
     * Setup user.
     */
    public function setup() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'init'] );
    }

    public function init () {
        register_post_meta(
            'vaenc_actu',
            '_vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles',
            [
                'show_in_rest' => true,
                'single'       => true,
                'type'         => 'array',
                'default'       => [],
                'auth_callback' => function() {
                    return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
                }
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

My javascript is like so:

```js
const {registerPlugin}                              = wp.plugins;
const {PluginDocumentSettingPanel}                  = wp.editPost;
const {PanelBody, CheckboxControl}                  = wp.components;
const {useSelect, select, withSelect, withDispatch} = wp.data;
const {Fragment, useState}                          = wp.element;
const {__}                                          = wp.i18n;
const {compose}                                     = wp.compose;

const RolesControl = ( {isChecked, updateMeta} ) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Fragment intialOpen={true}>
                <CheckboxControl
                    label={__( "PRI", "vae" )}
                    checked={isChecked( 'vae-pri' )}
                    onChange={( value ) => updateMeta( 'vae-pri', value )}
                />
                <CheckboxControl
                    label={__( "PRC", "vae" )}
                    checked={isChecked( 'vae-prc' )}
                    onChange={( value ) => updateMeta( 'vae-prc', value )}
                />
                <CheckboxControl
                    label={__( "Certificateurs", "vae" )}
                    checked={isChecked( 'vae-certif' )}
                    onChange={( value ) => updateMeta( 'vae-certif', value )}
                />
            </Fragment>
        </>
    )
}

const RolesField = compose( [
    withSelect( () => {
        return {
            actu_scope_meta: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles,
        };
    } ),
    withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => ({
        isChecked ( prop ) {
            let meta = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles;
            if ( meta ) {
                return meta.includes( prop );
            }
            return false
        },
        updateMeta ( prop, value ) {
            let meta = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )._vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles;
            if ( !meta ) meta = []

            if ( meta.includes( prop ) && !value ) {
                meta = meta.filter( arrayItem => arrayItem !== prop );
            } else if ( !meta.includes( prop ) ) {
                meta.push( prop );
            }

            dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( {meta: {_vaenc_actu_roles_scope_roles: meta}} );
        },
    }) ),
] )( RolesControl );

const Render = () => {
    const postType = useSelect( select => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType() );
    if ( 'vaenc_actu' !== postType ) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
                name="vae-role-scope-sidebar"
                title={__( 'Restrictions', 'vae' )}
            >
                <RolesField/>
            </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
        </>
    )
}

registerPlugin( 'vae-role-scope-sidebar', {
    render: Render
} )
```

Comment: i'm no expert but I think the problem might lay in the fact that you are not using the `actu_scope_meta` property that you are setting in withSelect. I think if you would add this to your function like this `const RolesControl = ( { isChecked, updateMeta, actu_scope_meta } ) => {` and then check for `actu_scope_meta.includes('value')` it might work.

Comment: I think the problem is that WordPress is a huge mess that is held together with bandaids in an attempt to keep it working. See issue https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/28032. Developing a kernel is easier than dealing with this React mess.